# integer expression expected -- linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I wrote a bash script that reads a variable from a textfile using:

```
XX=`sed -n -e ''"$row"'p' $filename | awk '{print $4}'`

echo $XX
12.88
```

then I want to test whether this number is greater than 12.5. If it is, then the variable `ex` should be set to 1200.

```
if [ "$XX" -ge 12.5 ]
    then
        ex=1200
else
    echo boo

fi
```

When I run this script I get the following error:

```
[: 12.88: integer expression expected
```

When I `debug` my code, it seems the variable is being assigned correctly. Here's the output:

```
+ echo 12.88
12.88
+ '[' 12.88 -ge 12.5 ']'
./test.sh: line 33: [: 12.88: integer expression expected
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `bash` shell does not do floating point, it's strictly concerned with integral values (and strings of course, but that's another matter). From the `bash` man page (my italics):

> **`arg1 OP arg2`** - `OP` is one of `-eq`, `-ne`, `-lt`, `-le`, `-gt`, or `-ge`. These arithmetic binary operators return true if `arg1` is equal to, not equal to, less than, less than or equal to, greater than, or greater than or equal to `arg2`, respectively. `Arg1` and `arg2` may be *positive or negative integers.*

You can do these sorts of comparisons using a tool like `bc`, which *does* understand floating point:

```
pax$ if (( $(bc <<<'3.14159 > 2.71828') )) ; then
...>    echo pi is greater than e
...> else
...>    echo pi is not greater than e
...> fi
pi is greater than e

pax$ if (( $(bc <<<'3.14159 < 2.71828') )) ; then
...>    echo pi is less than e
...> else
...>    echo pi is not less than e
...> fi
pi is not less than e
```

This works because `bc` can take a floating point comparison and gives you `1` if it's true, `0` otherwise.

In case of needing comparison with a variable, make sure you use double quotes so the variable is interpreted:

```
xx=3.14
pax$ if (( $(bc <<<"$xx < 2.71828") )) ; then
...>    echo xx is less than e
...> else
...>    echo xx is not less than e
...> fi
xx is not less than e
```

You can also include arbitrary expression within `bc` and have `bash` just interpret the comparison result of `0` or `1`:

```
pax$ xx=4 ; if (( $(bc <<<"$xx < 5 || $xx > 7") )) ; then echo not 4-6 ; fi
not 4-6
pax$ xx=5 ; if (( $(bc <<<"$xx < 5 || $xx > 7") )) ; then echo not 4-6 ; fi
pax$ xx=9 ; if (( $(bc <<<"$xx < 5 || $xx > 7") )) ; then echo not 4-6 ; fi
not 4-6
```

Comment: I already tried this command `if (( $(bc <<<'$XX < 12.5') )); then echo bla` and I tried the command you just gave me. I got the following error `(standard_in) 1: illegal character: $
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: X`

Comment: @aloha, if you use *single* quotes `'`, environment variables won't be substituted and the `$` will be given as-is to `bc`. Try using double quotes `"`: `xx=10 ; if (( $(bc <<<"$xx < 12.5") )); then echo bla ; fi`

Comment: it worked with `"` though I didn't quiet understand why. I guess I need to understand how `bash` operates.

Comment: @aloha: because double quotes allow variable expansion, single quotes don't :-)

Comment: what if I want to write something like this `    if (( $(bc <<<"$XX -ge 12.5") )) &&  (( $(bc <<<"$XX -le 13") ))` I get an error `(standard_in) 1: parse error` as in `XX>=12.5 and XX<=13`

Comment: @aloha, you do *that* in `bc` as well, see the update...